# How to kill watchdog Daemon on Linux

Tags: linux, fedora, process, kill, watchdog

I configured my watchdog.conf, and i want try if my computer restart when it crash. so, I wanted kill my Watchdog to try if my computer will restart.

[image: screenshot of pid of watchdogd]

But I try to killed it with the command "kill -9 90" and "killall -s SIGKILL watchdog" but neither of two successfulled.

If someone have an idea to kill the watchdogd ?

Best regards.

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397).

Comment: You need to check what module it is using, if any, then `rmmod` it. This is the only way to stop it from userland.

Answer (score 2):

In general, tasks that ps shows enclosed by [brackets] are kernel threads.

**There is just no way to kill a kernel thread from userland**. Period.

The only way I know is to make it crash writing to /dev/mem with more or less predictable consequences. (Care! going that way, the probability of crashing something else than what you precisely want is almost… certain)

In the particular case of the watchdog daemon, its behaviour can nevertheless be directed using some options, via some configuration file.
It can even be tested, see the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/watchdog) (under *Test directory* paragraph).

Comment: Unless you rmmod the module.

Answer (score -1):

A better way to test the watchdog demon is by suspending it. You can achieve that using the `kill*` command.

`killall -STOP watchdog`
Thiswill suspend the `watchdog` process unless it gets `SIGCONT` and the watchdog timer eventually reset the computer after the timeout.